# "System.Reflection.TargetInvocation Exception" in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating windows phone 8.1 app, I have added WCf service in Windows Phone, When I check WCF service, it returns the result, but whenever I am trying to call in Windows Phone project, it is giving me error.

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocation Exception
```

InnerException also remains "NULL", so can't getting the main issue

How to deal with this, this is headache for me.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the simple code:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
client.xxxxAsync(id,name);
client.xxxxCompleted += client_xxxxCompleted;

void client_xxxxCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.xxxxCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  e.Result = "Giving Error" - "TargetInvocation Exception"
}
```

I am also getting this error:

```
"Error loading XAML, clr-Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Comment: [Are you working together?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26261051/2681948) ;)

Comment: @Romasz both projects are in same solution. I am also getting "Error loading XAML"

Comment: @BinjalShah Are you creating a Silverlight 8.1 app or Windows Runtime app?

Comment: @Alovchin silverlight app, thanks for ur response

Comment: @Alovchin my XAML designer is not loading, but able to deploy and run the application. Please help me brother!!

Comment: @BinjalShah Is there anything in the InnerException of this TargetInvocationException?

Comment: @Alovchin nothing bro, thts the problem, inner exception shows null

Comment: @BinjalShah Well, basically TargetInvocationException means that the an invocation of a delegate (seems to be an event handler) has failed. Since you haven't provide any reasonable code, it's hard to tell what's wrong with your event. You should revisit your event invocation code.

Comment: @Alovchin ok, brother!!is it XAML issue, because in my call back method, e.Result giving error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62696/discussion-between-alovchin-and-binjal-shah).